# What is a "User Initiated Transaction"?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

There are many solutions on the web for using Entity Framework and getting this error:

> Execution strategy 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not
> support user-initiated transactions

I ran into this issue and followed the recommended fixes on the internet and I no longer have the problem in that one sql transaction I was doing.  The problem is, I need to find other areas of my app that could cause the same issue and fix them.  How can I do this when I don't know what a "User initiated transaction" is.  I've looked all over the web including Microsoft's knowlege article on this issue [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-resiliency/retry-logic?redirectedfrom=MSDN#limitations) but they don't define this term.

I "think" it is when you are using a `transaction scope`, or a `using BeginTransaction()` but I would rather not guess.

Can someone define this term please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user initiated transaction is a database transaction you or some code started using a `SqlTransaction`. For example:

```cs
using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(strConnString))    
{    
   objConn.Open();    
   objTrans = objConn.BeginTransaction();    
   SqlCommand objCmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into tblProject values(1, 'TestProject')", objConn);    
   SqlCommand objCmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into tblProjectMember(MemberID, ProjectID) values(2, 1)", objConn);    
   try    
   {    
      objCmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();    
      objCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Throws exception due to foreign key constraint   
      objTrans.Commit();    
   }    
   catch (Exception)    
   {    
      objTrans.Rollback();    
   }    
   finally    
   {    
      objConn.Close();    
   }    
}
```